# Depuracion de datos

Tags: excel, vba

Como puedo depurar datos en un cierto rango de tiempo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera tener solo los datos que se encuentran de color Blanco los de color verde quisiera eliminar y tenerlos de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este caso te sugiero que tengas en cuenta este [enlace](https://exceltotal.com/evaluar-el-color-de-fondo-de-una-celda/) para evaluar el color de fondo de una celda y mediante un array con un bucle `for` puedas conseguir lo que necesitas.

En todo caso, el código que avances sería bueno que lo publiques, con ello la comunidad te podrá orientar mejor y aquellos que tengan más adelante la misma inquietud se verán beneficiados también de la respuesta.